# Trichotomy of natural numbers Proof (Alternate proof Showing atleast one statement Tao's analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, induction, natural-numbers

I am reading Tao's analysis. in the book the proof of Trichotomy of natural numbers use proposition 2.2.12 and Definition 2.2.11.

The proof is divided in to two parts

1. Not more than one statement is true
2. Atleast one statment is true.

For second part Tao uses induction. Is the following a valid proof which is much simpler.

From Definition 2.2.11 (Ordering of natural numbers) we know $a \ge b$  which is equvivalent to $a = b+m$ for some natural number $m$. Now either $m=0$ or $m \neq 0$. If $m=0$ then $a=b$. If $m \neq 0$ then $a \gt b$, again by definition of ordering of natural numbers. Similary we can show for $b \ge a$. Hence Proved at least one statement is true.

Comment: It seems like you did not show why $a\le b$ or $a\ge b$. Is it proved already in the book?

Comment: @Riemann Perhaps you are right This is not explicitly stated

Comment: The first thing you should do in *any* proof is state the full result you intend to prove, including any conditions the result requires. You not only fail to do this, I am guessing you are not even sure yourself. "Trichotomy of natural numbers" is just a label not a mathematical result, and one that is not even widely recognized. Actually state the theorem first. If you do not know exactly what you are going to prove, you *will not be able to prove it*, and if we do not know exactly what you going to prove, then we cannot tell if you have proved it.

Comment: If I do an internet search trichotomy of natural numbers is referred to as law. Looks like it is well recognized property of natural numbers atleast. But I think I should have mentioned explicitly what Propositions/Theorems I can use to prove it.

Comment: I didn't say the *property* was not known. It is the name "Trichotomy property of natural numbers" that you should not expect people to automatically understand without context. There are multitudes of trichotomies one can prove about natural numbers. For example, every natural number is prime or composite or idempotent. Just saying "Trichotomy" without context is not enough to tell people what you are doing. Then you start with "we know $a \ge b$". No *we* don't, because this the first *we* have heard of them. You may know things about them, but you haven't told us.

Answer (score 0):

[[ This is mostly a Comment which is too long to Put in Comment Box ]]

Initially that Proof is looking good but there are Difficulties ....
There 3 Issues with that Proof :

(1) Your Proof uses the Lemma : "$a \ge b$" or "$b \ge a$" : Was the Lemma known or Proved ?

(2) How do we know that the Lemma is "Mutually Exclusive" ? It is not "Mutually Exclusive" here.

(3) How can we state that Both true will give $a=b$ ? Otherwise , we might get Both true giving "$a>b$ AND $b>a$" : we have to show that is not Possible.

[[ Elaborating Point 3 : "$X \lor Z$" AND "$Y \lor Z$" Both true can occur when $Z$ is true : It can even occur when $X$ AND $Y$ are true !
In other words : "A greater than OR EQUAL to B" AND "B greater than OR EQUAL to A" can occur when "A EQUAL B" : It can occur even when "A greater than B" AND "B greater than A" ! ]]

Comment: I think (2) and (3) follows from anitsymmtery of the Order (Proposition 2.2.12  (c))

Comment: I had a look at Definition 2.2.11 + Proposition 2.2.12 : (1) It is not yet given that "Either $A \le B$ or $A \ge B$" (2) When we Prove that , we can (2A) Either "Prove & use anti-symmetry to get $A = B$" or (2B) "Move to $A < B$ or $A > B$ with your argument" , which will complete the trichotomy. You have given (2B) which is correct , but there are some gaps like (1) & (2A). Other than that , your alternate Proof is valid.